# Percorrer e coletar dados de dicionários dentro de uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho uma lista com vários dicionários contendo dados cadastrais:

[{'sexo': 'M', 'idade': 44}, {'sexo': 'F', 'idade': 33}, {'sexo': 'M', 'idade': 55}]

Criei funções separadas para calcular a média, e a quantidade de pessoas do sexo feminino/masculino (e também a porcentagem)

Mas meu problema está em passar o parâmetro para essa funções, e como percorrer essa lista para coletar os dados (por exemplo, uma estrutura de repetição para coletar os dados de 'idade' para calcular a média.), como eu faria esse acesso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer de diversas maneiras, por exemplo você poderia empacotar estes dados em uma classe mas como você disse já tem funções separadas uma forma simples de fazer é assim:

```py
meus_dados = [
    {'sexo': 'M', 'idade': 44},
    {'sexo': 'F', 'idade': 33},
    {'sexo': 'M', 'idade': 55}
]

def media(dados):

    total, itens = 0, 0

    for item in dados:
        valor = item.get('idade', 0)
        if valor:
            itens += 1
            total += valor

    return (total / itens) if itens else 0


print(media(meus_dados))
```

Você pode envia a lista completa para a função, daí varre elemento por elemento (o `for`) usando o método `.get()` para recuperar o valor da chave que você procura* e encontrando você realizar a operação.

Repare que meu código só soma as idades caso elas existam, se for o caso o incremento de `itens` deve ficar do lado de fora do `if ...`.

(*) o segundo parâmetro é o valor padrão caso não exista a chave, consulte a documentação para maiores informações).

Comment: Ah, no Python 3.8 em diante você pode usar o operador _walrus_ e apenas fazer `if valor := item.get('idade', 0): ...`

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra abordagem seria utilizar `reduce`:

```
import functools 

dados = [{'sexo': 'M', 'idade': 44}, {'sexo': 'F', 'idade': 33}, {'sexo': 'M', 'idade': 55}]

def reduzir(anterior, atual):
  anterior[atual['sexo']]['qtde'] += 1
  anterior[atual['sexo']]['idade'] += atual['idade']
  return anterior

base = { 'M': { 'idade': 0, 'qtde': 0 }, 'F': { 'idade': 0, 'qtde': 0 } }
functools.reduce(reduzir, dados, base)
```

O resultado é:

```
{'F': {'idade': 33, 'qtde': 1}, 'M': {'idade': 99, 'qtde': 2}}
```

Dessa maneira você tem o resultado separado por sexo, podendo fazer a média por sexo ou geral.